# How to Implement GCD in Swift 2

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

Every time that I attempt to use dispatch methods such as "dispatch_get_main_queue()" Xcode tells me that the method is undefined. How do I enable these methods in Xcode?

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: If the method `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is not recognized, it's probably because you didn't `import Foundation`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `Foundation` or `UIKit` framework imported in your file, if you import `UIKit` it already uses `Foundation`.

Then you will be able to use it like this:

```
import Foundation

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // some main queue code
}
```

You may call right after a background context:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH  
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // do some task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // some main queue code
    }
}
```